# Changing margins removes page number

Tags: margins

I've used \newgeometry \restoregeometry to change the margins of one page so I can fit two images onto it. However as a result of this, the page number for that page has disappeared. The page is still counted, as the page following that (with the restored margins) has a page number as if the page before existed.

Comment: probably the margins are so big that the footer lies outside your page?

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the case. I don't see why it doesn't put the footer in the same place regardless of the size of the margin

Comment: Consider the implications of not having a strict spacing policy on the footer, placement, now a simple page geometry change would inflict the footer position. The consistency in document creation would then be _non_ trivial. `LaTeX` is so _smart_ that it will not allow page text to overlap footers/headers. That is more consistent, and also, expected, from a document processing tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page layout is rather strict. There are certain rules in the `geometry` package which governs the placement of the footers, etc.

So in your case the footer disappears from the paper. This can be circumvented by adjusting the length `\footskip`. This length is defaulted to `30pt` (use `\the\footskip` to print its value in the document). So what you would do is decrease it. That can be done via the option in the `\newgeometry` macro called `footskip=<length>`.

Whenever in doubt of how the pagelayout is put, add the `showframe` option in the preamble. This will let you easily see any mistakes or misinterpretations of the page-layout.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=6cm,showframe,textheight=3cm,textwidth=4cm}

\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{a}
\clearpage
% Decrease it to half its size
\newgeometry{textheight=3cm,textwidth=4cm,footskip=15pt}
Hello\footnote{b}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following two pages:

[image]
[image]